# Wpf Application not properly responding to events

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a very simple application, but it is giving a problem. I have a button (on a Grid), and I want to know , when a user clicks on it at run time, which part of button (X,Y coord.) the user clicked. Now, I cannot track the mouse position in Click event handler since its parameter "e" is of type "RoutedEventArgs", and it doesn't give position of point where mouse click happened.

Therefore I tried the other event handler, the "MouseLeftButtonDown" event. This has a parameter "e" which gives a GetPosition() method that can give mouse cursor position. But the problem is that at run time this event handler is not called at all when I click the button! Here is my code for both event handlers:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string sName = sender.GetType().Name;
        string sSrc = e.Source.ToString();
        string soSrc = e.OriginalSource.ToString();

        MessageBox.Show("Sender Name: " + sName + ",\nSource: " + sSrc + ",\nOrigSource: " + soSrc + ",\nevent:" + e.RoutedEvent.ToString());
    }

    private void button1_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        string sName = sender.GetType().Name;
        string sSrc = e.Source.ToString();
        string soSrc = e.OriginalSource.ToString();
        textBox1.Text = "LeftButtonPressed on button1";
    }
```

If I keep only click event handler, it works. If I keep only MouseLeftButtonDown event handler, it doesn't work. If I keep both, then only the Click event handler is invoked! can anybody help please??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: remove the messagebox

Answer (score 0):

The `Button` control swallows up (marks as "handled") the `MouseLeftButtonDown` event as part of its `Click` event.  It is possible to add a listener that fires even when the event has been handled, which you do like this:

```
button1.AddHandler(Button.MouseLeftButtonDownEvent, 
    new MouseButtonEventHandler(button1_MouseLeftButtonDown), 
    true // also capture handled events
);
```

Alternatively, you could subclass [`Button`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.buttonbase.onmouseleftbuttondown%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and override its `OnMouseLeftButtonDown` event:

```
public class ExtendedButton : Button
{
    protected override void OnMouseLeftButtonDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, can you please explain in a bit more details, as to what happens to MouseLeftButtonDown and MouseLeftButtonUp events for a Button? if Click event swallows these events, what can we do if we want different functionality for mouse button up and mouse button down events? any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @user2755525 as I mentioned in the answer, you can always add a handler manually in your code (I don't think you can add a "handled-events-too" listener from XAML).  I just added another alternative -- `Button` provides a protected override for the left mouse click, so you could create a subclass and handle it that way.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you help. I will try these options. Thanks again.

Comment: @user2755525 no prob. To address your other question -- it might help to notice that `RoutedEventArgs` has a `Handled` property.  Typically a handler will set `args.Handled=true` so that other controls will not double-handle it.  This is what the `Button` control does, and also raises its own `Click` event.